# I get an error when launching Automatic1111

Tags: python, error-handling, stable-diffusion

(Heads up that I know close to nothing about coding. I just watch tutorials and follow along)

Hi! I recently installed [Automatic1111](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) for Stable Diffusions web UI, but whenever I try to launch it I get this error message in the command prompt:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'lib' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Student\OneDrive - Xenter Botkyrka\Dokument\A1111 Web UI Autoinstaller\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py)
```

What can I try to solve it?

(I have tried re-installing python and Anaconda)

Comment: Automatic1111 is a GitHub username. See https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111 and [Why AUTOMATIC1111 is named like this?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/179/12)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it! The problem was that A1111 was installed to my Documents folder while the documents folder were synced with Onedrive, which led to A1111 be located there as well. I stopped the sync, installed A1111 in my regular documents folder and run the app with no problem!